# Problems using oauth with Electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

Im attempting to obtain an oauth token using "Implicit grant flow" in my electron app. The issue Im having is when the oauth service (in this case Twitch) redirects my electron app to the redirect uri with the token in it. When redirected the BrowserWindow seems to crash (error can be seen below). I've tried listening to multiple events provided by the BrowserWindow but all of them seem to not trigger before the crash. I've following multiple guides on how to make oauth work within Electron but none of them seem to actually work. If anybody has any success in doing this, Id very much appreciate a solution. Thanks.

Error message after being redirected

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (-102) loading (redirect uri with token in it)
```

Code

```js
const redirect = 'https://localhost/';
const authApp = new AuthApp(cid, redirect);

function handleAuthApp(url: string) {
    const urlD = new URL(url);
    console.log(urlD);
    authApp.reset();
}
//Event that will trigger the AuthWindow to appear
ipcMain.on('get-auth', async (event, arg: any) => {
    const window = await authApp.getWindow();
    window.show();
    window.on('close', () => {
        authApp.reset();
        console.log('closed');
    });
    // These events seem to never trigger 
    window.webContents.on('will-navigate', function(event, newUrl) {
        console.log(`Navigate: ${newUrl}`);
        handleAuthApp(newUrl);
    });
    window.webContents.on('will-redirect', function(event, newUrl) {
        console.log(`Redirect: ${newUrl}`);
        handleAuthApp(newUrl);
    });
    const filter = {
        urls: [redirect+'*']
    };
    const { session } = window.webContents;
    session.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect(filter, details => {
        const url = details.url;
        console.log(url);
        event.returnValue = url;
        window.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was awaiting the URL to load before the 'will-navigate' events could be set. So the BrowserWindow would crash before the events could be fired.
Im dumb.